# A low-cost linux-capable pc that can run chrome/ium with hardware acceleration?

Tags: linux, touchscreen

I basically need a (arch)linux box to connect a touchscreen monitor(HDMI) to and run a single chrome/ium window in full-screen. So basically a kiosk app.

The web-app has css animations and generous amounts of angular, so the graphics stack has to perform well (cpu too ofc), it being a visually focused app and all. This is actually for a 2nd touchscreen - I have the Apps backend hosted on an intel NUC (intel gpu) and powering one screen, I just couldn't get the two displays to work from the one NUC(or multiseat to work from one GPU - even though there are 2 HDMI outputs), so I figured a quick solution is to just get a cheap device to power the 2nd display.

I was considering a Rasberry Pi 3 - but I don't own one, so I'm not sure how well Chrome performs. There's also the intel's Compute Stick, but I don't know if that's any good, seems like some people got ubuntu to run on  it okay.

The only other requirement is an ethernet port, at least one USB port and a case (as for rasberry pi 3). Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Are you running the touchscreen through USB?

Comment: @PeterZhu yes, usb and hdmi.

Comment: I have heard that graphics drivers for the Raspberry Pi 3 are a bit unoptimized. I've watched YouTube videos with Chromium on my PI 3 with HDMI 23" 1920x1080 display. Changed GPU to use 256MB system memory and ran fairly well with Logitech 2.1 speakers. Raspbian has Chromium which is not Chrome but Chrome is built on top of Chromium so all the CSS and render engine is same. Plug-in support for things like widevine used by Netflix that are problematic. Pi 3 has 4 USB ports and Ethernet port and WiFi, which I have used, and Bluetooth, which I have not. Model B has 1GB of RAM. microUSB for power.